# increasing memory usage in listview

Tags: c#, sqlite, ram, maui

I create maui windows app that show over 3000 person's data in listview in one of pages .
the problem is : when enter the page of list view the memory usage increase but when back memory usage not released.
i use sqlite as database.

```
public partial class AllPerson : ContentPage
{
    DbContext _dbContext = new DbContext();
    
    public AllPerson()
    {
        ShowPersons();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    void ShowPersons()
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people = _dbContext.GetAllPerson();
        AllPersonList.ItemsSource =people ;
    }
}
```

Comment: _The bigger question is why you are attempting to show 3000 anythings in a GUI app?_

Comment: Memory gets released whenever GC decides it needs to run. If GC doesn’t think there is a memory problem yet, then it won’t run yet. This is typical behavior of all Garbage Collection systems. If you devise a test that crashes due to memory shortage, then post the details. The native OS (IOS, Android, or Windows) may be able to keep memory usage lower, but until you’ve shown that is a problem, it is not a problem.

Comment: CollectionView has built in paging and incremental loading

Comment: @MickyD I have a lot of data... What should I'm gonna do? Actually my problem is when push page ram usage increase but when pop page memory does not decrease

Comment: When I push page ram usage increase but after pop the ram usage does not decrease. So even I show only ten person data when I back to that page over and over ram usage is going high

Comment: _"I have a lot of data... What should I'm gonna do?"_ - Windows ListView control (and the .NET equivalent) has a feature called _virtual list view_ in which the _illusion_ of showing millions of items can be handled but in reality, only a tiny subset (perhaps 100s, user-configurable) are loaded into memory at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the `Memory Leak`. As an alternative workaround, you can write a virtualizing `ListView` or directly use `CollectionView`. For more detailed information, you can refer to [ListView/CollectionView memory leak under Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9162).